# Get the transfer function when using the "designfilt" command in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, filters, lowpass-filter, transfer-function

To put things into perspective, I initially had these four graphs in MATLAB, whose data were sampled with a rate of 10 samples/sec :-

[image]

I wanted to remove some of the spikes on the blue graphs, so I thought about making a lowpass-filter that would take care of that. I used the command `d = designfilt('lowpassfir','Filterorder', 5, 'CutoffFrequency',0.1,'SampleRate',10)` . I then put the data from the blue graph through the filter, and plotted again. Now they look like this:-

[image]

As can be seen, some of the spikes have been removed and the graph have been smoothed out, which is what I desire. However, now I want to get the transfer function for the filter, but the only output I get in MATLAB is

```
d = 

 digitalFilter with properties:

         Coefficients: [0.0287 0.1430 0.3283 0.3283 0.1430 0.0287]

   Specifications:
    FrequencyResponse: 'lowpass'
      ImpulseResponse: 'fir'
           SampleRate: 10
      CutoffFrequency: 0.1000
          FilterOrder: 5
         DesignMethod: 'window'
```

So my question is, can I just translate the coefficients directly into a transfer function of 5th order and with no zeroes? Like this:-
$$H(s) = \frac{1}{0.0287s^5 + 0.1430s^4 + 0.3283s^3 + 0.3283s^2 + 0.1430s + 0.0287} $$

If not, how can I get the transfer function from my designed filter?

Also, I didn't rigorously derive the arguments for the `designfilt`  command (filterorder, cutoff frequency) I just guessed at some appropriate values.

Comment: Hmm... didn't tf(d) work in this? https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/tf.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter is a discrete FIR filter, so the transfer function would be given as:

$$H(z) = .0287 + 0.1430z^{-1} + 0.3283z^{-2} + 0.3283z^{-3}+0.1430z^{-4}+0.0287z^{-5}$$

With the frequency response given by using the unit circle for the complex variable $z$, as in $z = e^{j\omega}$ for $\omega \in [0, 2\pi)$, with the sampling rate normalized to $\omega = 2\pi$.
You can use the `freqz` command in Matlab to plot or return the frequency response:

```
freqz([0.0287 0.1430 0.3283 0.3283 0.1430 0.0287])
```

Which creates a plot similar to what I have done using Octave below for these coefficients:

[image]

The frequency axis will be normalized to the radian angular sampling frequency, but you can refer to Matlab's documentation for other parameters that can be passed in to `freqz` to scale the frequency otherwise.